# Organizing CSS using collapsible sections...?

Tags: css

I'm sure this don't exist right now but i figured it didn't hurt to ask, so in most IDE's and code editors you are able to collapse a section of code to hide it.  This is usually when something appears within {}. What i would like to know is can you create a grouping for similar sections within CSS? Here is what i am asking...

```
nav {
  ...
}

nav ul {
  ...
}

nav ul li {
  ...
}
```

take a section of css that is aimed at a section within the whole webpage and contain it like...

```
nav section { // i know this won't work but its the best way i can illustrate
  nav {
    ...
  }

  nav ul {
    ...
  }

  nav ul li {
    ...
  }
}
```

so that way i can use say sublime text to collapse the nav section instead of collapsing each peace individually?

Answer (score 0):

Using a pre-processor such as [Less](http://lesscss.org/) you can actually change your syntax to:

```
nav{

   ul{

      li{

      }
   }

}
```

And therefore you would be able to collapse by `nav`.

Comment: That is really nice, and most certainly would solve my question. Thanks a ton.